# how to count updates in java variable

Tags: java, variables

Is there any way to find the number of updates of the specific variable?
Assume `int a =5;`.  My java program has over 100 lines and over 20 functions. Most of the `a` get updated. At the end of the program I need to find how many time it got updated.

```
int a = 5;

a=10;
a=20;
a=a+1;
a=a+10;

system.out.println("number of updates " + ????); //should be 4
```

Comment: Nope, that information is lost. Keep a counter of modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have this information natively in the `int` primitive type.

But, you could wrap your `int` in a class:

```
public class Int {
    private int value;
    private int update = 0;

    public Int(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value){
        update++;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public int getUpdate(){
        return update;
    }
}
```

Your example, with the wrapper class would output `4`

```
Int a = new Int(5);
a.setValue(10);
a.setValue(20);
a.setValue(a.getValue() + 1);
a.setValue(a.getValue() + 10);


System.out.println("number of updates " + a.getUpdate());
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to have another variable that would count the updates of `a`. You would have to increment that variable each time `a` is updated.

If `a` is a member of some class (as oposed to being some local variable), this would be easier to achieve if you only use a `setA(int newValue)` method to modify `a`, and that setter method would increment the update count.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take another variable to store/update the count value of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move the variable out of the method and turn it into a field, yes.

```
int a = 5;
int counter = 0;

void setValue(int a) {
    counter++;
    this.a = a;
}

void foo() {
    setValue(10);
    setValue(20);
    setValue(a+1);
    setValue(a+10);

    System.out.println("number of updates " + counter);
}
```